# Confirming message received from Ardulink's sendCustomMessage() through serial.read()

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to send a string to arduino with the Ardulink Library's

```
link.sendCustomMessage();
```

and I would like arduino to confirm that message by sending it back to me through Serial.println(); However I am not getting anything from Arduino.

Following this code on the PC modified from the ardulink tutorial:

public class InputTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Link link = Link.getDefaultInstance();

    link.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void disconnected(DisconnectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Board disconnected");
        }

        @Override
        public void connected(ConnectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Board connected");
        }
    });

    link.connect("COM5");
    try {
        System.out.println("wait for a while");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("proceed");
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("start Listening");

    while(true)
    {
        link.sendCustomMessage("omglol");
    }
}
```

}

Following this code on the Arduino:

```
String inData;
void setup()
{
     Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop()
{
    inData="";
    if (Serial.available() > 0) 
{
int h=Serial.available();    // if you are getting escape -characters try h--; here
for (int i=0;i<h;i++)
{
   inData += (char)Serial.read();
}
// if you are getting escape -characters try Serial.read(); here
}
    //print it out
   Serial.println(inData);
}
```

I don't know if im doing it right; but i am getting error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1024 at         org.zu.ardulink.connection.serial.AbstractSerialConnection$SerialReader.run(AbstractSerialConnection.java:190)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is there an update for this question? I am having the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to terminate message from Arduino to Ardulink with a Serial.write(255);

Otherwise Ardulink store bytes in a buffer thinking that the message is not finished and don't process it. When the buffer is full the exception raises.

In order to see message back you have to add a Raw Listener to your Java code.